# Контент за пределами родителя

Tags: html, css

Есть родитель с параметрами:

```
position:relative;
min-height:500px;
```

Есть у этого родителя ребенок с параметрами:

```
position:absolute;
```

Вот в чем беда...

Если я заполню контент ребенка больше чем на 500пикселей - он просто выйдет за пределы родителя.

Но если я в родителе просто наполню текста больше чем на 500 пиксселей - он начинает тянутся, все верно.

Вопрос:
**Как реализовать что бы блок-детенышь был с *абсолютным* позиционированием и при превышении максимальной ширины родителя тянулся?...**

Comment: не совсем понятно. можете fiddle добавить с примером?

Comment: не совсем ясно для чего вообще пользоваться в этом случае absolute для потомка , он и так находится внутри и не выйдет за пределы при правильных стилях

Comment: В некоторых ситуациях я использую для родителя position:relative, потому что у меня несколько детей с position:absolute, неважно почему и зачем, у меня бывают такие ситуации, и вот тогда и возникает такая беда..

Comment: Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/Lrn7n721/

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите, чтобы родитель тянулся по мере увеличения ширины ребенка?
https://jsfiddle.net/wg0ae2aw/1/ - как-то так.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 500px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

Если размер дочернего элемента будет превышать максимально возможный размер родительского - тут вы уже ничего сделать не сможете, контент будет выходить за пределы. Задав дочернему эл-ту width: 100% он сам будет заполнять всю область родителя, даже если будут какие-то ограничения, как тут - https://jsfiddle.net/wg0ae2aw/3/

---

Так-как ребенок с абсолютным позиционированием, родитель не будет растягиваться под него никак. Можно сделать такой весьма грязный трюк - https://jsfiddle.net/wg0ae2aw/5/

```
$('.container').height($('.child').height())
```

Родитель принимает высоту дочернего элемента.

Comment: По высоте хотел, а не по ширине.
Если я ребенку задаю высоту 100% он берет высоту родителя 100%, все правильно, можно добавить overflow и будут полосы прокрутки.
Но это не подходит просто

Comment: У Вас  в примере если добавить еще контента в 3 раза больше - так же выйдет за пределы родителя

Comment: @user197892 Может быть потому что для родителя задан height: 500px? :)

Comment: это я игрался и не заметил что забыл добавить min-height. Всё равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Так может вести себя только viewport:

```css
body, html {
  /*position: relative;*/ /* не влияет на результат */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9y7wsvf/

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.parent{
    width:70%;
    margin:30px auto;
    background: #fafafa;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.child{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.child p{
    margin:20px 0;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:1.1vw;
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    p{
        font-size:14px !important;
        text-align: justify;
        margin:20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent"> 
      <div class="child"> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.   Tempora, voluptatibus, reprehenderit accusantium optio repellat ullam aperiam nihil voluptatum molestiae, doloremque architecto itaque! Voluptatibus doloribus laborum quo optio consequatur eveniet, veritatis itaque culpa omnis modi ullam provident sint tempora commodi nihil hic aspernatur rerum, et laboriosam. Ea sunt voluptate itaque rerum id quod ullam distinctio cum odit veniam explicabo doloribus corporis sit ipsum, et provident dolor dolorem deserunt quisquam ex maxime, reprehenderit similique consequatur! Aperiam nulla provident voluptatum repellendus architecto distinctio laboriosam alias doloribus reiciendis perspiciatis? Quos, dolorum ipsa eum aliquam quaerat doloremque ullam, sed laudantium nihil recusandae, reiciendis odit accusantium!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem accusamus possimus odio vel sapiente nesciunt culpa nam eveniet facilis eligendi labore ab totam harum quis velit enim, consectetur aspernatur nihil, molestias atque similique consequatur quaerat! Necessitatibus expedita qui vel reprehenderit. Repudiandae, impedit. Asperiores ea, expedita suscipit fugiat consequuntur nihil amet hic reiciendis quis mollitia cum perferendis odio commodi, eveniet ipsum.
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi hic nam modi veritatis, perferendis magnam aperiam inventore tempore odit, id quisquam ad voluptatibus sunt, molestiae ipsam dolorum harum consequatur pariatur cupiditate. Non et perferendis ea, praesentium tempore id commodi distinctio molestiae possimus enim necessitatibus nihil, vitae ipsa qui quod, eius optio maxime beatae eum! Molestias fugit a, autem vitae recusandae unde officia quam incidunt quod tempora eaque nesciunt, asperiores blanditiis.</p>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вы поясните для чего вообще применять в вашем случае абсолютное позиционирование ? Как видите текст не выйдет за пределы родителя ни каким образом

Comment: Автор вы по моему мнению не совсем понимаете для чего применяется это свойство css